# changePassword.bat wastool fails for the Workload Scheduler user

Tags: change-password, tivoli-work-scheduler

Trying to change password for the Workload Scheduler user, by using the changePassword.bat wastool:

```
changePassword.bat -user tws94mdm -password mypassword
```

in the generated output, the following error messages are present:

```
ERROR : install service <tws_tokensrv_tws94mdm> failed  
System error <430>   
The specified service has been marked for deletion.        
"IBM Workload Scheduler Token Service (for tws94mdm)" service updated

ERROR : install service <tws_maestro_tws94mdm> failed    
System error <430>  
The specified service has been marked for deletion.   
"IBM Workload Scheduler (for tws94mdm)" service updated
```

All the Workload Scheduler services are marked for deletion, with the exception of the IBMWAS85Service.

When the master machine is restarted, all processes are deleted and the master instance is unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes of the problem are:

- One of the following applications is opened:

  - SysInternals' Process Explorer
  - Task Manager
  - Microsoft Management Console (MMC)
  - Services console
  - Event Viewer
- The key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services{service name} does exist
- Someone else is logged into the server and has one of the previously listed applications opened

In case the changePassword tool fails due to a service marked for deletion, you must restart the server and rerun the changePassword tool in the wastool folder to recover the master instance.